# Colocar valores dentro de selects, para CRUD

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, ajax

```
    <?php require('erp_layout/header.php'); ?>

<section id="main-content">

<section class="wrapper">

<h3><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Pesquisar pedidos pendentes</h3>

<div class="row mt">

<div id="modal">
  </div>
  <div class="pop-up-father">
    <div class="pop-up">
        <div class='top'>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark cerrar"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="container-form-popup">
            <div class="form-popup showback">
                <form id="pedido">
                    <ul class="shopping_cart">
                        <li >
                        <label for="ropa">Roupa: </label> 
                                <select id="ropa" name="ropa">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione o tipo de roupa</option>
                                <?php

                                    $connection->set_charset("utf8");
                                    $query = $connection -> query ("SELECT * FROM ropa");
                                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {       
                                echo '<option value="'.$valores['id'].'">'.$valores['ropa'].'</option>';
                                    }
                
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="piezas">Peças S/I e Mais: </label>
                                <select id="piezas" name="piezas">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione o tipo de peça S/I</option>
                                </select>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="piezas_ropa">Tipos de peças: </label>
                                <select id="piezas_ropa" name="piezas_ropa">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione o tipo de peça</option>
                                </select>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="sector">Setor de atividade: </label> 
                                <select id="sector" name="sector">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecionar Setor de atividade</option>
                                <?php

                                    $connection->set_charset("utf8");
                                    $query = $connection -> query ("SELECT * FROM sector_de_actividad");
                                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$valores['id'].'">'.$valores['sector'].'</option>';
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select></li>

                            <li>
                            <label for="tela">Tecido: </label>
                                <select id="tela" name="tela">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione um Tecido</option>

                                </select></li>
                            <li>

                            <label for="color">Serigrafia (Cor): </label>
                                <select id="color" name="color">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione o Cor</option>                     
                                </select></li>
                            <li>
                            <label for="tamano">Tamanho: </label> 
                            <select id="tamano" name="tamano">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione o tamanho das peças de roupa</option>
                                <?php
                                $connection->set_charset("utf8");
                                $query = $connection -> query ("SELECT * FROM tamaño");
                                    while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$valores['tamaño'].'">'.$valores['tamaño'].'</option>';
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label for="cantidad">Quantidade: </label>
                                <input type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" min="30" placeholder="Mínimo é de 30 peças de roupa" style="width:300px;">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label for="pago">Formas de pagamento: </label>
                                <select id="pago" name="pago">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione o tipo de pagamento</option>
                                <option>Pix</option>
                                <option>Boleto</option>
                                <option>Transferencia - Bradesco</option>
                                <option>Transferencia - Santander</option>
                                <option>Transferencia - Itau</option>
                                </select>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <button id="btnguardar" class="button_shopping_cart">Alterar carrinho de compras</button> 
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div id="modal">

 </div>   

 <div id="datos-orders">

 </div>   

 </section>

</section>

<?php require('erp_layout/footer.php'); ?>
<script>
     function eliminar(id) {
         console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
                url: 'php/deletePedidosEnviados.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id:id.id},
            })
            .done(function(respuesta){
                console.log(respuesta);
                if (respuesta ==0) {
                    var aux =document.getElementById("modal");

                    aux.classList.add("correcto");
                    aux.innerHTML = "<p>Limpeza de dados bem sucedida</p>";
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        aux.classList.remove("correcto");
                        aux.innerHTML = "";
                    }, 3000);
                }
                else if(respuesta ==1){
                    var aux =document.getElementById("modal");
                    aux.classList.add("incorrecto");
                    aux.innerHTML = "<p>Não foi possível excluir. Tente novamente mais tarde</p>";
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        aux.classList.remove("incorrecto");
                        aux.innerHTML = "";
                    }, 3000);
                }
            })
            .fail(function(){
                console.log(respuesta);
            });
            var e = document.getElementById(id.id);
            e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);
    }
 </script>
 <script>
    var cartid;
    $("#btnguardar").on("click",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var ropa = document.getElementById("ropa").value;
        var piezas = document.getElementById("piezas").value;
        var piezas_ropa = document.getElementById("piezas_ropa").value;
        var sector = document.getElementById("sector").value;
        var tela = document.getElementById("tela").value;
        var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
        var tamano = document.getElementById("tamano").value;
        var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
        var pago = document.getElementById("pago").value;
        console.log(ropa);
        if (ropa != "" && piezas != "" && piezas_ropa != "" && sector != "" && tela != "" && color != "" && tamano != "" && cantidad >= 30 && pago!= "") {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'php/changeCartSend.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id_pedido:cartid.id, ropa:ropa, piezas:piezas, piezas_ropa:piezas_ropa, sector:sector, tela:tela, color:color, tamano:tamano, cantidad:cantidad, pago:pago},
            }).done(function(respuesta){
              console.log(respuesta);
              if (respuesta ==0) {
                var aux =document.getElementById("modal");
                aux.classList.add("correcto");
                aux.innerHTML = "<p>Modificação de dados bem-sucedida</p>";
                setTimeout(() => {
                  aux.classList.remove("correcto");
                  aux.innerHTML = "";
                  window.location.reload();
                }, 3000);
                
               
                var pop = document.getElementsByClassName('pop-up-father')[0];
                pop.classList.remove('activ');
              }
              else if(respuesta ==1){
                    var aux =document.getElementById("modal");
                    aux.classList.add("incorrecto");
                    aux.innerHTML = "<p>Não foi possível alterar, tente novamente mais tarde</p>";
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        aux.classList.remove("incorrecto");
                        aux.innerHTML = "";
                    }, 3000);
                }
                var pop = document.getElementsByClassName('pop-up-father')[0];
                pop.classList.remove('activ');
                
            })
            .fail(function(){
                console.log(respuesta);
            });
        }
        else{
          var aux =document.getElementById("modal");
                    aux.classList.add("incorrecto");
                    aux.innerHTML = "<p>Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos, o pedido é no mínimo => 30</p>";
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        aux.classList.remove("incorrecto");
                        aux.innerHTML = "";
                    }, 3000);
        }
    });
    function alterar(id) {
        var pop = document.getElementsByClassName('pop-up-father')[0];
        pop.classList.add('activ');
        console.log(document.getElementById('ropa').innerHTML);
        cartid = id;
    }
    var close = document.getElementsByClassName("cerrar")[0];
    close.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        var pop = document.getElementsByClassName('pop-up-father')[0];
        pop.classList.remove('activ');
    });

</script>
<script>
  //Función que indica que el documento está listo
  $(function(tipo_ropa){ 

    //Detectar el cambio de opción del sector
    $(document).on('change','#ropa',function(){

      //borrar las opciones que están cargadas en las telas
      $('#piezas option').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
      });

      //Guardar valor seleccionado
      var ropa = $(this).val();

      //Validar que no esté vacío o nulo
      if( ropa && ropa != '' ){

        //Abrir conexión de AJAX
        $.ajax({
          url:'../assets/php/shopping_cart_information_tipos_de_ropas.php', //URL donde está el archivo que busca las telas
          method: 'GET', //Verbo de petición del protocolo
          data: {ropa:ropa}, //Información que se enviará al PHP
          success:function(respuesta){
            //Respuesta satisfactoria

            //Validar si se creó correctamente el JSON
            if( respuesta.success ){
              var i = 0;

              //Agregar opción por default a telas
              $('#piezas').append('<option disabled selected>Selecione o tipo de peça</option>');

              //Recorrer el nodo de información recopilada
              for (i; i < respuesta.data.length;) {

                //Armar la opción y agregarla al SELECT de telas
                let option = '<option value="' + respuesta.data[i].id + '">' + respuesta.data[i].ropas + '</option>';
                $('#piezas').append(option);
                i++;
              }      

            }

            else{
              alert( respuesta.message );
            }
          },
          error:function(err){
            alert( err );
          }
        });
      }

    });

  });
</script>
</select>

<script>
  //Función que indica que el documento está listo
  $(function(tipo_piezas_ropa){ 

    //Detectar el cambio de opción de las piezas
    $(document).on('change','#piezas',function(){

      //borrar las opciones que están cargadas en las telas
      $('#piezas_ropa option').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
      });

      //Guardar valor seleccionado
      var piezas = $(this).val();

      //Validar que no esté vacío o nulo
      if( piezas && piezas != '' ){

        //Abrir conexión de AJAX
        $.ajax({
          url:'../assets/php/shopping_cart_information_piezas_ropa.php', //URL donde está el archivo que busca las telas
          method: 'GET', //Verbo de petición del protocolo
          data: {piezas:piezas}, //Información que se enviará al PHP
          success:function(respuesta){
            //Respuesta satisfactoria

            //Validar si se creó correctamente el JSON
            if( respuesta.success ){
              var i = 0;

              //Agregar opción por default a telas
              $('#piezas_ropa').append('<option disabled selected>Selecione o tipo de peça</option>');

              //Recorrer el nodo de información recopilada
              for (i; i < respuesta.data.length;) {

                //Armar la opción y agregarla al SELECT de telas
                let option = '<option value="' + respuesta.data[i].id + '">' + respuesta.data[i].ropa + '</option>';
                $('#piezas_ropa').append(option);
                i++;
              }      

            }

            else{
              alert( respuesta.message );
            }
          },
          error:function(err){
            alert( err );
          }
        });
      }

    });

  });
</script>
</select>

<script>
  //Función que indica que el documento está listo
  $(function(Sector){ 

    //Detectar el cambio de opción del sector
    $(document).on('change','#sector',function(){

      //borrar las opciones que están cargadas en las telas
      $('#tela option').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
      });

      //Guardar valor seleccionado
      var sector = $(this).val();

      //Validar que no esté vacío o nulo
      if( sector && sector != '' ){

        //Abrir conexión de AJAX
        $.ajax({
          url:'../assets/php/shopping_cart_information_telas.php', //URL donde está el archivo que busca las telas
          method: 'GET', //Verbo de petición del protocolo
          data: {sector:sector}, //Información que se enviará al PHP
          success:function(respuesta){
            //Respuesta satisfactoria

            //Validar si se creó correctamente el JSON
            if( respuesta.success ){
              var i = 0;

              //Agregar opción por default a telas
              $('#tela').append('<option disabled selected>Selecione o tipo de tecido</option>');

              //Recorrer el nodo de información recopilada
              for (i; i < respuesta.data.length;) {

                //Armar la opción y agregarla al SELECT de telas
                let option = '<option value="' + respuesta.data[i].id + '">' + respuesta.data[i].tela + '</option>';
                $('#tela').append(option);
                i++;
              }      

            }

            else{
              alert( respuesta.message );
            }
          },
          error:function(err){
            alert( err );
          }
        });
      }

    });

  });
</script>
</select>

<script>
  //Función que indica que el documento está listo
  $(function(color){ 

    //Detectar el cambio de opción del sector
    $(document).on('change','#tela',function(){

      //borrar las opciones que están cargadas en las telas
      $('#color option').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
      });

      //Guardar valor seleccionado
      var tela = $(this).val();

      //Validar que no esté vacío o nulo
      if( tela && tela != '' ){

        //Abrir conexión de AJAX
        $.ajax({
          url:'../assets/php/shopping_cart_information_colores.php', //URL donde está el archivo que busca los colores
          method: 'GET', //Verbo de petición del protocolo
          data: {tela:tela}, //Información que se enviará al PHP
          success:function(respuesta){
            //Respuesta satisfactoria

            //Validar si se creó correctamente el JSON
            if( respuesta.success ){
              var i = 0;

              //Agregar opción por default a color
              $('#color').append('<option disabled selected>Selecione o tipo de cor</option>');

              //Recorrer el nodo de información recopilada
              for (i; i < respuesta.data.length;) {

                //Armar la opción y agregarla al SELECT de telas
                let option = '<option value="' + respuesta.data[i].id + '">' + respuesta.data[i].color +  '</option>';


                $('#color').append(option);
                i++;
              }      

            }

            else{
              alert( respuesta.message );
            }
          },
          error:function(err){
            alert( err );
          }
        });
      }

    });

  });
</script>
```

<< PHP que muestra el DATATABLE >>

```
    <?php
include("../../assets/php/connection.php");

$salida = "";
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM carro_de_compras
      INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.id = carro_de_compras.id_clientes
      WHERE carro_de_compras.pedido LIKE 'Enviado%'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

$tabla_estatus = "SELECT * FROM estados_pedidos";
$status_pedidos = mysqli_query($connection, $tabla_estatus);
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
    
    $salida.="<table id='example' class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed showback' cellspacing='0'>
                             <thead>
                                 <th>Cliente</th>
                                 <th>Roupa</th>
                                 <th>Peça S/I</th>
                                 <th>Peça</th>
                                 <th>Setor de atividade</th>
                                 <th>Tecido</th>
                                 <th>Serigrafia (Cor)</th>
                                 <th>Tamanho</th>
                                 <th>Quantidade</th>
                                 <th>Forma de pagamento</th>
                                 <th>Pedido</th>
                                 <th>Data</th>
                                 <th>Alterar/Excluir</th>
                                 <th>Status do pedido</th>
                             </thead>
                             <tbody>";

    while($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $tabla_estatus = "SELECT * FROM estados_pedidos";
        $status_pedidos = mysqli_query($connection, $tabla_estatus);
        $salida.="<tr>
                  <td id='".$valores[0]."'>".$valores['email']."</td>
                  <td>".$valores['ropa']."</td>
                  <td>".$valores['ropa_superior_inferior']."</td>
                  <td>".$valores['pieza']."</td>
                  <td>".$valores['sector_de_actividad']."</td>
                  <td>".$valores['tela']."</td>
                  <td>".$valores['color']."</td>
                  <td>".$valores['tamaño']."</td> 
                  <td>".$valores['cantidad']."</td>
                  <td>".$valores['forma_de_pago']."</td>
                  <td>".$valores['pedido']."</td>
                  <td>".$valores['data']."</td>
                  <td><button onclick='alterar(this)' id='".$valores[0]."' class='alterar'>Alterar</button>
                     <button onclick=eliminar(this) id='".$valores[0]."' class='excluir'>Excluir</button></td>
                  <td>
                  <select class='dropdown' id='".$valores[0]."' onchange=statusC(this)>";
        $aux = "";
            while($status_pedido = mysqli_fetch_array($status_pedidos)){
                if ($status_pedido["id"] == $valores['id_status_pedido']) {
                    $aux .="<option value = '".$status_pedido['id']."' selected=''>".$status_pedido['status']."</option>";
                }
                else{
                    $aux .= "<option value = '".$status_pedido['id']."'>".$status_pedido['status']."</option>";
                
                }
            }

        $salida = $salida.$aux."</select> 
        </td>
           </tr>";

    }            

    $salida.="</tbody>
           </table>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>";

}

echo $salida;

mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que se haga click en el botón "modificar", los datos de esa fila se cargue en los selects del "poup".

Cada vez que intento colocar los valores '.valores['ropa'].' y otros mas dentro de los selects, me toma ese valor como sino existiera.

He tratado diferentes formas de solventar este problema pero ya no encuentro solucion, este mismo metodo que quiero aplicar aqui, lo aplique con unos inputs tipo text, lo cual funciono perfectamente.